# Calculating cumulative summation using SQL based on Product Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have wrote an SQL query which allocates products to a customer based on the quantity remaining for each product in stock.

I.e. If OurQty = 55 and there are 70 outstanding orders split between 5 customers (Customer 1 = 35, Customer 2 = 10, Customer 3 = 3, Customer 4 = 16, Customer 5 = 6) then my SQL query will allocate the reserved product quantity to each customer sequentially until OurQty = 0 or all of the outstanding orders have been fulfilled.

My SQL query:

```
WITH allocate 
     AS (SELECT rd.ponum                                  AS PONum, 
                od.orderline                              AS OrderLine, 
                rd.partnum                                AS PartNum, 
                p.partdescription                         AS PartDescription, 
                od.ordernum                               AS OrderNum, 
                rd.ourqty                                 AS OurQty, 
                od.number01                               AS Reserved, 
                rd.ourqty - od.number01                   AS NewOurQty, 
                c.custnum                                 AS CustNum, 
                c.name                                    AS Name, 
                ( rd.ourqty - Sum(od.number01) 
                                OVER ( 
                                  ORDER BY od.ordernum) ) AS CumulativeSum 
         FROM   dbo.rcvdtl AS rd WITH (nolock) 
                INNER JOIN dbo.part AS p WITH (nolock) 
                        ON rd.partnum = p.partnum 
                INNER JOIN dbo.orderdtl AS od WITH (nolock) 
                        ON rd.partnum = od.partnum 
                INNER JOIN dbo.orderhed AS oh WITH (nolock) 
                        ON od.ordernum = oh.ordernum 
                INNER JOIN dbo.customer AS c WITH (nolock) 
                        ON od.custnum = c.custnum 
         WHERE  ( rd.ponum = 73 ) 
                AND ( od.number01 > 0 ) 
                AND ( od.openline = 1 )) 
SELECT ponum, 
       orderline, 
       partnum, 
       partdescription, 
       ordernum, 
       ourqty, 
       reserved, 
       newourqty, 
       custnum, 
       name, 
       cumulativesum + reserved AS 'Left In Stock', 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( cumulativesum + reserved ) - reserved > 0 THEN reserved 
         ELSE ( CASE 
                  WHEN ( cumulativesum + reserved ) > 0 THEN 
                  ( cumulativesum + reserved ) 
                  ELSE 0 
                END ) 
       END                      AS Allocated 
FROM   allocate
```

This works fine when the 'PartNum' is specified as a parameter. The problem arises when I query the table without specifying the 'PartNum' since the table contains multiple 'PartNums' which affects the accuracy of the 'CumulativeSum' which is used to check if (OurQty < CumulativeSum) and as such prevent the allocation of stock which does not physically exist.

My original idea was to pass the database table the 'PartNum' as a parameter for a given 'PONum' iteratively and then merge the results into one dataset on my application. Unfortunately the program I am using which calls the SQL query cannot pass the 'PartNum' to the SQL query as a parameter.

Therefore, Is it possible to calculate the cumulative sum for each PartNum in the table using SQL?

**I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012**

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are looking for, but you might look into the [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. It could help with cumulative sums. Also, have you considered a cursor? They are generally not recommended as they are much slower than set based approaches, but might be what you need.